# Complex sql query on BLK insert

Tags: sql

I am using following query to load data from text file into database table

```
bulk insert  Test_Training.dbo.test
from 'D:\SSRS\kasthuri.txt'
```

I have `kasthuri.txt` file in specified path. But I am getting error when I execute it.

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot bulk load because the file "D:\SSRS\kasthuri.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

Comment: If the SQL Server is running on another machine - is the file **on the SERVER's disk in the D: drive**??? Because the server really can not (and should not!!) reach down onto your own local `D:` drive....

Comment: Try to change the permissions on your txt file (just for the test you can give full permission to everyone)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is because the service running your SQL server instance cannot access the file path. Wherever you place the file, you will need to open up the folder where the file resides to the MSSQLSERVER agent:

**I always struggle with this. For me, allowing MSSQLSERVER full permission to the folder where the input file resides always seems to work.*

*Right-click the folder (as an admin on the box), go to properties, security, edit, add...
here is where I always get tripped up. For me, the server service account is "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER" and I can never search for that user. I have to type it in manually and check the name to make sure I typed it in correctly. For you, this may not be the service account used by your server. Check your services list from windows administrative tools to see what account is in "Log On As" for SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER).**

Comment: I am sql server 2012...can u help me ..How to activate that service

Comment: Me.. you shouldn't have to activate the service. If you're logging into SQL Server than it's already running.